# background-origin not working when border appears on hover

Tags: css, less, background-image

[In this Codepen](http://codepen.io/75th/pen/lkFcA), you'll see I have some links, each with multiple positioned background images. I've set a border to appear on hover, and everything on the site uses `box-sizing: border-box`. My understanding is that setting the `background-origin` CSS property to `border-box` should make those positioning styles render the same no matter what border is on it; the images should be positioned relative to the outer edge of content, padding, and border.

But when you hover over them, it looks like the `background-origin` isn't working at all. When the border appears, the background images shift to accommodate the space where the border is, thereby acting as though they were `background-origin: padding-box`. This happens in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

Is this a misunderstanding on my part, or a ubiquitous browser bug, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `background` shorthand property can be used to set almost *every* `background-` property, including `background-origin`. And when a shorthand property overrides a specific property, the web inspector doesn't show the specific one crossed out in its Rules panel. But if you look at the Computed Style panel, you can see that those link elements are still being computed as `background-origin: padding-box`.

Adding `!important` to the background-origin rule, copying it after the `background` rules, or adding it to the `background` rules themselves fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is because you don't *have* any border on those images until you hover over them.

If you add this `border:4px solid transparent;` to your `#block-menu-block-2 ul.menu li a` style definition the weird shifting when you hover goes away.

Comment: Yes, but you'll see if you add that that when the border appears, three sides of the border appear correctly, but one side extends the width of the box by those 4 pixels. Which is even more confusing than what I already had.

Comment: Ack. You're right. Sorry, I'd missed that it was doing that when I'd made the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For your `#block-menu-block-2 ul.menu li a` CSS rule, you have `border-box` under the wrong property, for what you're trying to do. Right now, you have it under `background-origin` which is wrong. What you're looking for is the `box-sizing` property. It should be like so:

```
#block-menu-block-2 ul.menu li a  {

    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;       

}
```

Now you can add `border: 4px solid transparent` to your "normal" state, it should be working the way you want it.

You can read more about this nice CSS property here:  http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Did you try to make those changes to the Codepen yourself? The very first rule in the CSS applies `box-sizing: border-box` to every element on the page. I further need `background-origin` to make the backgrounds behave correctly, but they're not behaving correctly.

Comment: I did and I tried it through Chrome developer tools. Worked for me